# Why QLineEdit with QCompleter for auto completion doesn't shows up?

Tags: c++, qt, autocomplete

I have two `QLineEdit`s in the program being `lineEdit` and `fileName_Edit`. `lineEdit` holds path to a directory (taken from user). Then user enters the name of file in the `fileName_Edit`. I want to show suggestions to user when he is entering the file name in `fileName_Edit`. I tried to implement `QCompleter` like this: 
(`dirContents` is a `QStringList` which holds the contents of the directory specified by user in `lineEdit`)

```
void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    QCompleter *fileEditCompleter = new QCompleter(dirContents, this);
    fileEditCompleter->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    fileEditCompleter->setCompletionMode(QCompleter::UnfilteredPopupCompletion);
    ui->fileName_Edit->setCompleter(fileEditCompleter);
}
```

Program compiles successfully but, the completer doesn't shows up. Even if I try to connect `textChanged` signal to the function like following, it doesn't shows up.

```
QObject::connect(&MainWindow::ui->lineEdit, SIGNAL(&textChanged(QString)), this,SLOT(&MainWindow::on_lineEdit_editingFinished()));
```

EDIT: Adding above line gives an error saying:

> Expected constructor, destructor or type-conversion before ( token

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to set completer _before_ providing `QLineEdit` to user. For example - in constructor of MainWindow. It is not correct to set it in textChanged slot.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov Thanks for replying, can you please give some example code for that ?

Comment: I don't think you need to create the Completer before the lineEdit. The Qt documentation does it the same way. But doing this in the textChanged slot, not sure if thats so good. It's also not completely clear where dirContents comes from. Have you made sure it is not empty? Are you sure this method was called? Maybe you want to call it with the editingFinished signal instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to do it simply first, if the code works, then everything is good and you can start improving it.

In constructor:

```
QDir dir("G:/2");//path here
QStringList dirContents = dir.entryList(QStringList(), QDir::Files);
qDebug() << dirContents;//make sure that you list isn't empty, or use isEmpty method
QCompleter *fileEditCompleter = new QCompleter(dirContents, this);
fileEditCompleter->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
fileEditCompleter->setCompletionMode(QCompleter::UnfilteredPopupCompletion);
ui->lineEdit->setCompleter(fileEditCompleter);
```

If this will work on your computer then you can be sure that your system and project are good, and start improve it (change list etc). And try not to use global variables.

If you want do it dynamically, create a simple model and when you will set new `QStringList` to it, your completer always will display new data

```
QDir dir("G:/2");
QStringList dirContents = dir.entryList(QStringList(), QDir::Files);

mdl = new QStringListModel(dirContents,this);//QStringListModel *mdl in header

QCompleter *fileEditCompleter = new QCompleter(mdl, this);
fileEditCompleter->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
fileEditCompleter->setCompletionMode(QCompleter::UnfilteredPopupCompletion);
ui->lineEdit->setCompleter(fileEditCompleter);
```

When you want change data when for example, user clicks button or something else, you can do:

```
QDir dir("G:/2/tmp");
mdl->setStringList(dir.entryList(QStringList(), QDir::Files));
```

Now your completer has new data.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I wanted to ask if i will do the QDir part of your code inside a function, then connect it with a QLineEdit signal then will it work? Do I have to do some other funcion to pass QDir object ??

Comment: @EdwardMckinzie As you can see, we need QDir here to get list of files, you can use this QDir everywhere BUT your list should be visible in all places where you want use it, because the most important things for you, it is list and information in this list, QDir is just a tool. I hope it helps. And one more: if you found my and other answers useful, can you vote up it please(upper triangle pressing)? Thank you too. http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Comment: Hey, Is it somehow possible to modify the contents of the dirContents later in the rpgram for example use a QLineEdit or something?? If yes how. This is because when the constructor runs it just has files of path in `QDir dir()`  and not what user enters in lineEDit. So no matter which path I enter in lineEdit, the Qcompleter shows the files present in the directory of dir(). Is my way of doing it is wrong?? And also I dont think constructor can be called after the start of class/program. So can you please suggest a method for the above mentioned issue?? I will check out your other answers.

Comment: @EdwardMckinzie If I set `QDir dir("G:/2/tmp");
mdl->setStringList(dir.entryList(QStringList(), QDir::Files));` to the buttonClicked slot it change the data in model when I press the button succesfully.

Comment: Yes, I has put `QDir dir("G:/2/tmp"); mdl->setStringList(dir.entryList(QStringList(), QDir::Files));` to a pushButton clicked slot but its not working, I don't know why

Comment: @EdwardMckinzie Did you my path? What if you haven't G:/2/tmp, try to set existing path in your system and check is your new stringList isn't empty, because if it is empty, then completer will be empty too.

Comment: Yes that wasn't the issue. Anyways I fixed the problem, Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Converting comment to an answer, as requested...

Try to set completer before providing QLineEdit to user. For example - in constructor of MainWindow. It is not correct to set it in textChanged slot.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
  : QWidget(nullptr)
  , ui( new ui_MainWindow() )
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
  //...
  QCompleter *fileEditCompleter = new QCompleter(dirContents, this);
  fileEditCompleter->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
  fileEditCompleter->setCompletionMode(QCompleter::UnfilteredPopupCompletion);
  ui->fileName_Edit->setCompleter(fileEditCompleter);
}

void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
  // Do nothing here
}
```

Comment: Actually, dirContents is a global variable, which gets its value from another local qstringlist. So when i tried your method, its giving me an error saying `dirContents is not declared in this scope` :(

Comment: I took care of the above error by making a function which returns dirContents. But the problem is that, it still doesn't seem to work. Anny ideas??

Comment: +1 , OP's code seems very complicated and can has many errors, I suggest him to start with something simple and start to do more and more complicated things.